# how to save custom trained model without full connect layer just like MobileNetV2 include_top=False

Tags: tensorflow

i want to save my trained model to .h5 without last two layers, in order to transfer learning using my custom model in the furture, just like MobileNetV2 include_top=False, can someone help me, thanks!

```py
base_model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(
    alpha=1.0,
    input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet')

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    base_model,
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(255, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

trained model like this:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Model) (None, 2, 2, 1280)        2257984
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 1280)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 205)               262605
=================================================================
Total params: 2,520,589
Trainable params: 2,486,477
Non-trainable params: 34,112
_________________________________________________________________
```

when i try to using it for transfer learning

```
keras_model = loadModel(keras_model_path)
keras_model.summary()

input = keras_model.input
hidden = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(keras_model.layers[-3].output)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(hidden)
model2 = tf.keras.Model(input, out)
model2.summary()
```

an error occurs

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Comment: trained model like this:

Comment: Hey, did you get the solution I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to save my trained model to .h5 without last two layers,

why don't you save the full model with model.save() and when you reload it for transfer learning, just remove the layers using:

```
model.layers.pop()
```

You can also remove the layers before saving the model but I wouldn't do that

Comment: because i want to change softmax Dense form 128 to 255, i wan't to save a pure model just like MobileNetV2 with include_top=False, i don't know how to do

Comment: I don't know any option like include_top in saving models .. include_top is an option at loading models .. and what it does if set to True is loading the full model (MobileNetV2) then removing last layers so that you can plug your output with your correct dimensions .. 
Please provide more details.. maybe showing more code will help